# Constructor cannot be applied to the given types

Tags: java, oop, constructor

RootsOfQuadratic.java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class RootsOfQuadratic {
    public static void main(String[]args)throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter a, b and c of the quadratic equation.");
        double a = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        double b = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        double c = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        
        Roots roots = new Roots(a, b, c);  //This line has the problem
        roots.displayRoots();
    }
}
```

Roots.java:

```
public class Roots {
    private double root1, root2;
    
    public void Roots() {
    }
    
    public void Roots(double a, double b, double c) {
        calculate(a,b,c);
    }
    private void calculate(double a, double b, double c) {
        root1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(b*b - 4.0 * a * c))/2.0 * c;
        root2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(b*b - 4.0 * a * c))/2.0 * c;
    }
    public void displayRoots() {
        System.out.println("The roots are: "+root1+" and "+root2+".");
    }
}
```

The error says, "constructor roots in class Roots cannot be applied to given types;"
It says that the constructor needs to have no arguments. But I have a three argument constructor.

Also, an error showed up before which said, "cannot find symbol displayRoots". After closing and opening BlueJ, the error went away, but the constructor error didn't.

Comment: as raj360 answered, you have 2 methods that look like constructors but no actual constructor

Comment: Yes. Constructors have no return type.